# Объясните про кросс валидацию?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, валидация

Ранее для обучения нейросетей я использовал просто метод train/test split. Обучал модель на трейне и проверял качество на тесте. Теперь я освоил как делать кросс валидацию. Получил 5 фолдов, посчитал ошибки обучения в каждом фолде, получил среднюю ошибку по всем фолдам. Все понятно. Я прочитал документацию и инфу на форумах, но понял, что кросс валидация нужна для сравнения перфоманса разных моделей. Т.е. если бы я сделал xgboost и нейросеть, то можно было бы корректно сравнить какой метод лучше. Но, что если я просто обучаю одну модель - нейросеть с помощью кросс валидации. Значит ли это, что каждый фолд - отдельная модель нейросети, обученная на разных наборах данных соответственно? И по итогу, я должен выбрать лучшую модель, которая показала на своем фолде минимальную ошибку. Если это так, то как сохранить эту модель по конкретному фолду, чтобы использовать для предикта с реальными наблюдениями? Если нет, то выходит, что я просто обучаю на 5 фолдах после всех итераций и предсказываю результат через model.predict? Т.е. усредненный прогноз по 5 фолдам уже учитывается в модели? Спасибо заранее за помощь. Я новичок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете сразу несколько вещей между собой, что не удивительно в общем, поначалу это нормально.

Кросс-валидация обычно всё-таки применяется с одной моделью. Чтобы получить как бы больше тестовых оценок на том же количестве данных по сравнению с использованием отложенных данных для теста. И таким образом лучше определить производительность модели. Можно прогнать кросс-валидацию для разных моделей или для одной модели с разными параметрами и выбрать таким образом лучшую модель или лучшие параметры.

Выбирать модель под конкретный фолд смысла нет - вы не знаете, на что будут похожи реальные данные, по которым вам потом нужно будет предсказывать моделью, на этот фолд или на другой. Вы можете только сказать, что при обучении на вот этих данных и проверке на вот тех данных скор хороший, но это вам ничего не скажет о качестве предсказаний модели на новых данных. Модель в идеале должна хорошо предсказывать любые данные, поэтому и смотрят как модель себя ведёт в целом на всех данных при кросс-валидации. Один фолд сам по себе ничего не значит.

А далее, есть ещё такая штука как **стекинг**, и вот там тоже используется метод разбиения по фолдам. Учим модель на трейне - предсказываем тест. И так несколькими разными моделями. И по всем фолдам. Полученные предсказания объединяем в одну матрицу. И потом уже на этой матрице предсказаний учим ещё одну модель (обычно простую уже совсем - линейную регрессию). И вот эта модель второго уровня как бы сама уже выбирает, как лучше объединить предсказания разных моделей. Это чем-то похоже на кросс-валидацию, но не совсем.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый и своевременный ответ! Таким образом, когда моя модель (нейронная сеть) обучилась на 5 фолдах, то она учитывает на выходе опыт обучения на всех 5 кусочках тренеровочных и валидационных данных? Т.е. после обучения на кросс валидации я просто могу сделать предикт и не бояться, что он будет только на основе последнего пятого фолда? Еще раз большое спасибо за ответ! PS: Выходит, что стекинг это ансамбль нейронных сетей (или я ошибаюсь?).

Comment: @Madr Эээ, нет, не совсем так. Кросс-валидация - это метод **проверки качества модели**. Когда вы убедились с помощью кросс-валидации, что качество модели хорошее, вы потом должны обучить модель заново, уже на всех тренировочных данных целиком, без разбиения на фолды. Я, кстати, так когда-то давно потерял немного скора на каком-то соревновании на Kaggle - отложил немного данных для проверки качества модели, а потом забыл обучить модель заново на всех данных для финального предсказания.

Comment: @Madr Стекинг - это обычно ансамбль ансамблей )  Не обязательно нейронных сетей, наоборот, для него берут модели разного типа, чтобы у них были разные (но хорошие) предсказания - например, берут Random Forest, какой-нибудь бустинг, ну и какую-нибудь нейронную сеть. Хотя на самом деле RF уже давно не берут, он медленный, а вот бустинги нынче и быстрые и точные. А нейронные сети обычно используют для несколько специфических задач, где данных много и они многомерные - картинки, звук, тексты...

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все понятно и доходчиво объяснил. Буду применять теперь этот опыт на практике.